# CSS - How to space?

Tags: css, spacing

Hi Guys i'm new to CSS and wondering how do you take out the space on the left, right, top, bottom. i don't have cellspacing nor cellpadding.

Please see picture attached, the red arrow points to the space i want to take out. Hoping to stretch it to cover the space, but i don't know how to? i would appreciate the help thanks :)

Space that i want to take out is pointed by the red arrow

image: http://postimg.org/image/9xikjm2dz/

Comment: Please, post your code of what you have tried, or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="orange_area">
   <div class="white_Area">
   </div>
</div>

<style>
.orange_area{width:100%;}
.white_area{width:100%;margin:auto}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

depends what your code looks like, theres many ways of going about it, i can list a few but without knowing your code i cant give you an exact.

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
```

that would be my best go at it without seein your code

Comment: CSS code: http://s7.postimg.org/aywldyniz/css_code.png
INDEx html code: http://postimg.org/image/dn1f7j09t/

Thanks Sir